# Why does pep8 suggest using two spaces in comments?

Tags: python, coding-style, pep8

[PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#comments) states:

> You should use two spaces after a sentence-ending period.

In my usual refactoring, I am used to replacing such consecutive double spaces with a single one, thinking that this habit has come from the typewriter days (I have went through [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_spacing) briefly).
Also most of the times I have seen mono-space fonts being used for the programming, so it's much clearer than the other cases which can sometimes need 2 spaces to easily identify sentences.

Is there any reason behind this being used in PEP-8?

Comment: If your are refering to the sentence in the PEP8 link: 'You should use two spaces after a sentence-ending period' you should explicitly write that sentence to prevent ambiguity with line spacing or font styles (which you also mention).

Comment: I can't tell you how much it bothers me that your sentence doesn't end in a period.

Comment: @asmacdo: It was lost in the previous update(not by me). Does the newly added period make you happier :) ?

Answer (score 10):

Only those who authored the PEP can answer the "why" with any degree of certainty.

I've had a look at the [standard library source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/32af4954e46a/Lib), and my conclusion is that this particular aspect of the style guide is not followed consistently: some standard modules follow it and some don't.

Until you pointed it out, I've never heard of the double space convention, and have never noticed anyone following it.

Comment: Even I had never noticed this part of the pep8. I have always been using single spaces and none (including linters) objected. Just while re-checking some other guidelines for comments I noticed it. I think it's not a strict recommendation, and can be ignored if I am not convinced.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: readability :)

Comment: With mono-spaced fonts, The sentences are easily recognizable and the code/comments are readable too as the punctuation like "." or "," take the same horizontal space as any other character (or space), and the preceding space makes the gap look wider than a single space. Instead my eyes are a bit annoyed to see two or more spaces in a paragraph, and writing such a comment is also slightly more work.

Comment: How does it improve readbility? http://www.slate.com/articles/technology/technology/2011/01/space_invaders.html

Comment: @Clément As the article says, two spaces after a sentence is more readable for monospaced fonts, which are often used for displaying or editing code.

Comment: I think the readability of single-space comments is only affected if you don't have syntax highlighting (colors) in your text viewer, so the extra space helps. If you do have syntax highlighting then the double spaces become more annoying than helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The reasoning behind the double space still exists in code.

For people who believe that two spaces improves readability, the reasoning has become less relevant with regard to WYSIWYG editors with kerning. However, code is written in monospaced fonts, which means that if you want extra space between sentences, you have to put it there.

That being said, I prefer single spaces :)